# Export ipa with files in document folder

Tags: ios, xcode

My ios app saves images and text files in the app document folder so that the user is able to use the app offline. To avoid that he has to load this data at the first start, I would like to export the ipa with all necessary images and text files stored in the documents folder.

Ho can I do that? Is this even possible?

Comment: You can add all those files to the project and at first launch move them to Document folder.

Comment: That could be a way to do it, thanks! :)